# Sort rows of a multidimensional array by column value with a sticky first row when a particular value is found

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array, sticky

My multidimensional array is sorted alphabetically by the `OwnerNickName` field, but I need to make the `OwnerNickName = 'My House'` row as the sticky first row and then everything else sorted by OwnerNickname ascending.

Input:

```
[
    '0318B69D-5DEB-11DF-9D7E-0026B9481364' => [
        'OwnerNickName' => 'andy',
        'Rooms' => [ /* irrelevant */ ]
    ],
    '286C29DE-A9BE-102D-9C16-00163EEDFCFC' => [
        'OwnerNickName' => 'anton',
        'Rooms' => [ /* irrelevant */ ]
    ],
    '8BE18F84-AC22-102D-9C16-00163EEDFCFC' => [
        'OwnerNickName' => 'mike',
        'Rooms' => [ /* irrelevant */ ]
    ],
    '29B455DE-A9BC-102D-9C16-00163EEDFCFC' => [
        'OwnerNickName' => 'My House',
        'Rooms' => [ /* irrelevant */ ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Do you need to permanently rearrange the array? Or is the sort order variable?

Comment: Related: [Custom rows of a 2d array by multiple columns with one row "sticky" in last position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14415309/2943403) and [Sort array by keys ascending and nominate a "sticky" key to be first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46041666/2943403)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to implement your own sorting function, e.g.:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['OwnerNickName'] == $b['OwnerNickName']) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($a['OwnerNickName'] == 'My House') {
        return -1;
    } else if ($b['OwnerNickName'] == 'My House') {
        return 1;
    }
    return ($a['OwnerNickName'] < $b['OwnerNickName']) ? -1 : 1;
}    
usort($array, 'cmp');
```

Comment: Maybe use uasort if you want to keep your keys

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your mind about which index to sort on or which value should be special, something like this might suit:

```
function specialSort(array &$array, $index, $specialvalue){
    $callback = function($a,$b) use ($index, $specialvalue) {  //closure
       if ($a[$index] == $b[$index]) return 0;
       if ($a[$index] == $specialvalue) return -1;
       if ($b[$index] == $specialvalue) return 1;
       return ($a[$index] < $b[$index]) ? -1 : 1;
    }  ;

    uasort($array, $callback);
}

$arr=array(
    'a'=>array('thing'=>'yay','who'=>'owee'),
    'foo'=>array('thing'=>'boo','who'=>'wik'),
    'd'=>array('thing'=>'kil','who'=>'ilo'),
    'b'=>array('thing'=>'ser','who'=>'uyt'),
    'zed'=>array('thing'=>'efv','who'=>'qet')
);

specialSort($arr,'who','ilo');
print_r($arr);
```

Gives the result:

```
Array
(
    [d] => Array
        (
            [thing] => kil
            [who] => ilo //special value
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [thing] => yay
            [who] => owee
        )

    [zed] => Array
        (
            [thing] => efv
            [who] => qet
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [thing] => ser
            [who] => uyt
        )

    [foo] => Array
        (
            [thing] => boo
            [who] => wik
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the original first level keys, `uasort()`. Pass the sorting rules to the callback as two-element arrays to be compared by the spaceship operator.  Because `false` is "less than" `true`, check if the OwnerNickName is NOT equal to My House to make it the sticky first element.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dpp1T))

```
uasort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) => [$a['OwnerNickName'] !== 'My House', $a['OwnerNickName']]
                  <=>
                  [$b['OwnerNickName'] !== 'My House', $b['OwnerNickName']]
);
var_export($array);
```