# Sort associative multidimensional array by keys on all levels

Tags: php, sorting, recursion, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have following array:

```
$data['uploads']['ccc'] = 'something';
$data['uploads']['bbb'] = 'something';
$data['uploads']['aaa'] = 'something';
$data['downloads']['ccc'] = 'something';
$data['downloads']['aaa'] = 'something';
$data['downloads']['bbb'] = 'something';
```

And I need it alphabetically sorted by keys, so final results needs to be:

```
$data['downloads']['aaa'] = 'something';
$data['downloads']['bbb'] = 'something';
$data['downloads']['ccc'] = 'something';
$data['uploads']['aaa'] = 'something';
$data['uploads']['bbb'] = 'something';
$data['uploads']['ccc'] = 'something';
```

Tried with various custom sort function, no luck.. Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Associative array sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957587/php-associative-array-sort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ksort($data);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Also from the comments in the PHP documentation:

Here is a function to recursively sort multidimentional arrays by key:

```
function deep_ksort(&$arr) { 
    ksort($arr); 
    foreach ($arr as &$a) { 
        if (is_array($a) && !empty($a)) { 
            deep_ksort($a); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This function won't run recursively... when it returns, only the keys of the outer-most array will be sorted.

Comment: @Christopher Armstrong i just added a function "deep_keysort" to handle multidimensional did you see it?