# Custom rows of a 2d array by multiple columns with one row "sticky" in last position

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, sticky

I have one array, say `$xyz` containing:

```
[
    7399 => [
        'count' => 103,
        'name' => '2&ordm; SEMESTRE - 2012',
    ],
    7398 => [
        'count' => 50,
        'name' => '1&ordm; SEMESTRE - 2012',
    ],
    7397 => [
        'count' => 43,
        'name' => '2&ordm; SEMESTRE - 2011',
    ],
    7396 => [
        'count' => 20,
        'name' => '1&ordm; SEMESTRE - 2011',
    ],
    7395 => [
        'count' => 53,
        'name' => '2&ordm; SEMESTRE - 2010',
    ],
    'others' => [
        'name' => 'Others',
        'count' => 65,
    ],
]
```

I want to sort this array by count desc, name asc leaving 'others' element at the bottom.
I have used array_multisort like below

```
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($xyz as $key => $row) {
    $count[$key]  = $row['volume'];
    $name[$key] = $row['edition'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($count, SORT_DESC, $name, SORT_ASC, $xyz);
```

but failed. It show following warning:

```
Warning: array_multisort() [function.array-multisort]: Array sizes are inconsistent
```

Want i want is something like this

```
array
    7399 => 
        array
            'count' => int 103
            'name' => string '2&ordm; SEMESTRE - 2012' (length=23)
    7395 => 
        array
            'count' => int 53
            'name' => string '2&ordm; SEMESTRE - 2010' (length=23)
    7398 => 
        array
            'count' => int 50
            'name' => string '1&ordm; SEMESTRE - 2012' (length=23)
    7397 => 
        array
            'count' => int 43
            'name' => string '2&ordm; SEMESTRE - 2011' (length=23)
    7396 => 
        array
            'count' => int 20
            'name' => string '1&ordm; SEMESTRE - 2011' (length=23)
    'others' => 
        array
            'name' => string 'Others' (length=6)
            'count' => int 65
```

Comment: Did you try with `usort()` ?

Comment: @romainberger: usort sorts the array with user-defined function. If i would be able to do define a function that can sort array/solve my problem, why would i post a question her. Anyways, Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1):

There's already been a [well-written answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699110/427992) for this problem:

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}
```

So, to sort by count, you do:

```
aasort($your_array,"count");
```

Comment: i dont know why it doesnt worked when i tried what you have specified in your answer but the link that you have specified in your answer has helped me a lot. Thanks for the link.

Comment: i would have loved to. But, its not your answer that has solved my problem. Its the one whose link you have specified. So, i have upvoted you answer. Thanks a lot for that. Seriously...

Answer (score 0):

Build arrays that express your rules in the callback of `usort()`, then use the spaceship operator to compare the data.  `$a` on the left side and `$b` on the right side of the operator means ASC; and vice versa.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EMoch))

```
uasort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        [
            $a['name'] === 'Others',
            $b['count'],
            $a['name']
        ]
        <=>
        [
            $b['name'] === 'Others',
            $a['count'],
            $b['name']
        ]
);
var_export($array);
```