# Sort rows of a 2d array by specific value in one column, then by values in another column

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, php-5.6

I have an array:

```
[
{id: 1, status: 2, temperature:14}
{id: 2, status: 2, temperature:21}
{id: 3, status: 4, temperature:12}
{id: 4, status: 2, temperature:31} 
{id: 5, status: 1, temperature:35} 
]
```

I'd like to sort the array by: `status = 2` first, `temperature desc` second.

so it needs to sort based on two "columns". The above needs to output :

```
[
{id: 4, status: 2, temperature:31} 
{id: 2, status: 2, temperature:21}
{id: 1, status: 2, temperature:14}
{id: 5, status: 1, temperature:35} 
{id: 3, status: 4, temperature:12}
]
```

DISCLAIMER: I'm on PHP version 5.6.4; I cannot use spaceship operator.

Comment: Implementation of [Sort rows of a multidimensional array by column value with a sticky first row when a particular value is found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77864587/2943403): https://3v4l.org/rDYN7

Comment: this is different, the question you commented above only answers for sorting on one column, im sorting on multiple columns;

Comment: You changed the question -- that is not a failure in my page closure. https://3v4l.org/nAtFH  If you edit your question any more, please be sure to write valid json and include your coding attempt.

Comment: There are plenty of pages which demonstrate how to sort on multiple columns: [Sort multidimensional array by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647220/2943403) and [Properly sorting multidimensional array using usort and spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309755/2943403) and [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175345/2943403) to name a few.

Comment: Show me how the example handles mine? No where do i see a value = something. This really feels like youre just trying to promote your old answers without actually seeing that our requirements are different

Comment: You didn't see my updated demo link for your updated question in my second comment? https://3v4l.org/nAtFH  Maybe you just want this: https://3v4l.org/e7pUi which is also demonstrated on this page from 2012: [Sort rows of a 2d array with a particular "sticky" value in a column first, then sort by another column ascending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78183348/2943403)  I am surprised to be slandered as selfish while I am generously supplying you with multiple reference pages and multiple working snippets while your question shows no coding attempt.

Comment: In the provided solutions, you don't see `value = something` because they are built with `value !== something`.  This is because `false` evaluations are sorted before `true` evaluations.

Comment: your solutions only work for php 8 and above. We need solutions for prior versions too. reopen this question

Comment: No reason to reopen. I've extended my advice on the dupe target to cover unsupported/outdated versions of PHP.

Comment: Yes, the answer to the question here is indeed to write a custom sort function, as is answered in the duplicate target. That custom sort function can then implement whatever one wants, such as having a specific scalar value beat every other sort values then sort normally, etc.